# How to use flow_from_directory function when we want implement cross validation

Tags: python, keras, cross-validation

I have a small image dataset which I employed ImageDataGenerator class in Keras to augment my dataset. I put my dataset in a folder so I take advantage of flow_from_directory function to load and use the images.

Now I have to implement k-fold on my code. and I don't know how to manage my dataset since the name of each image is its label.

Does anybody have any idea to handle this situation?

Comment: `flow_from_dataframe` is the way to go

Comment: Why do you want to use k-fold-cross validation in that case? Is your data set such small?

Comment: unfortunately both small and I wanna be sure that my model is accurate enough for my whole data @ixeption

Comment: that's great!!! it is the best solution. I didn't familiar with this function. thank you so much @FalconUA